# How to Refresh a Div by Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I need to Refresh a Div in Page by Jquery

```
<? if($POST['id']) :?>
<script>
    Refresh script
</scriptt>

<?php ednif;?>

<div class="Refresh-Div">
           <span> Some Dynamic Content </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear... do you mean you want to load some content from somewhere else (e.g. a server side script) into a `div` via AJAX?

Comment: If $POST['id'] is Present then i need to refresh the DIV

Comment: "Refresh" as in what? Load new content? You can't just "refresh" a `div` as you can an entire page.

Comment: Yes i need to Load a new content

Comment: @Cakephp.Saint : from where you want to load the content? from any link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure what you are looking for, but based on your comments on the question, you want something like this:

```
$(".Refresh-Div").load("someScript.php");
```

That is the simplest form the the jQuery `load` function, which simply loads whatever is returned by `someScript.php` into the element with `class="Refresh-Div"`, replacing whatever was there before.

You can do more with the `load` function if necessary (like pass in data, and a callback function), so for more information I suggest reading the `load` section in the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/load/).

Answer (score 0):

By refresh do you just mean change the content?  If so, the .html() method will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can refresh it using a callback from an Ajax method like [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)(), get(), or post(), or you can modify it (works like a refresh) using html(), append() or other [manipulation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) functions. The effect will be immediate.