# Jquery / Ajax refresh div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Is it possible to use Jquery / Ajax to refresh a div but don't load a php file in the Jquery script?

Every jquery script I found requires a file to load but that's not possible because then my variables are not set.

```
<div id="reloadDIV">
<?php // PHP in here.. ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you don't want to load from a server-side resource, what do you want to load?

Comment: Sorry I don't know how I can be more clear than this. The DIV that needs to be reloaded contains PHP which makes calls to my DB etc. But if I use the "normal" Jquery refresh I need to load the PHP page instead of adding the PHP inside the <div></div> which makes the DB calls etc. impossible for the loaded PHP file unless I re-script all my PHP pages.

Comment: make your php code which is inside DIV also run during ajax call at server side then return the result & insert it into the DIV.

Comment: @HirdeshVishwdewa That will be a LOT php code, so it's not possible to refresh the div and it's content?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Refresh a Div by Jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545016/how-to-refresh-a-div-by-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are loading data dynamically from any php file like file.php than do this.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
       var container = $("#reloadDIV");
        container.load("file.php");
        var refreshId = setInterval(function()
        {
            container.load('file.php');
        }, 9000);

});
```

```html
<div id="reloadDIV">
<?php // PHP in here.. ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I tried this and the problem is that my code in file.php would require to include some other files to make the DB connection and get some other variables to function, and that's what's going wrong.

Comment: make db.php here write db connection code. include it in the top of the file , than do this , it will work

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking to update data in the div that is being pulled from a database, Ajax could be a good approach.See here: [jQuery Ajax simple call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19015897/jquery-ajax-simple-call)

Then in your ajax file you just need to return the data and it will update the div. You could then use a timer function to call the ajax request periodically